# Redirect in IIS using Variables ($1$2)

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis, url-rewriting, iis-7

I have a redirect set up like this

```
<rule name="EN" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="en/(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="$1$2" />
</rule>
```

However, it is not working properly. I'm trying to get it to be so when a user types in [www.mysite.com/en/anything.aspx](http://www.mysite.com/en/anything.aspx). That it redirects to [www.mysite.com/anything.aspx](http://www.mysite.com/anything.aspx)

I have a feeling I've set something up wrong, maybe incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your condition get a match so you know that part is OK?
I dont think you use $1 $2 but {R:1} {R:2} etc.

```
<action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
```

I have not tested this, but I would try this:

```
<rule name="EN" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="en/(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}" />    
</rule>
```

Comment: Would this be the same for something where more than one directory follows the (.*)? So en/*/*??

Comment: Yes. Everything matching the first (.*) will be {R:1}, the next () will be {R:2} etc.