# my rewrite rule doesn't redirect

Tags: asp.net, iis, mod-rewrite

I added the following to IIS7

[image]

but when I surf to `http://localhost:85/toolbar/apps/`

I get 404 from the server and not redirect.

Comment: Are you trying to make the url http://localhost:85/apps when http://localhost:85/toolbar/apps is requested? If yes, I think you need to use {R:1} instead  of $1 in your redirect URL. Refer this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124987/redirect-in-iis-using-variables-12)

Comment: can you post detailed  error log from IIS ? 
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/266/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis/ . I have an Idea, but I need some information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know about IIS7 Rewrite Url Module,but you can try this:

Pattern:`^toolbar/(.*)`

Redirect Url:`{R:1}`

Answer (score 0):

so, is there any page or service available in that folder? 
if there is nothing you gave that message, 
 good luck!